# Writing to NFS mounted directory gives 'Operation not permitted' - how to configure permissions?

Tags: pantheon-files, files

I am running 5.0 Juno, and I have a NFS share mounted with settings such that the owner and group can read, write, and execute. On the client machine, the mount command shows the following configuration

```
192.168.1.x:/mnt/pool0/share on /nfs type nfs (rw,relatime,vers=3,rsize=131072,wsize=131072,namlen=255,hard,nolock,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=192.168.1.x,mountvers=3,mountport=698,mountproto=udp,local_lock=all,addr=192.168.1.x)
```

With these settings, tools like touch, cp, and mkdir work as normal in the terminal.

In contrast, when using Files to write files to the share, I get the error

```
Error opening file “/nfs/Documents/new file”: Operation not permitted
```

however, after receiving the error, an empty file is created on the share.
A second attempt to write the file allows for a full write.

My question is: how do you configure permissions for Files to resolve this error?

Comment: Is the error shown in a Files dialog?  I cannot match it to any error message in the source code.